# About of Apache 2.0 License

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0, open-source-definition

Hello everyone I'm going to use for my app ios the Google library "Tink" for cryptography End To End ... This library is released under an Apache 2.0 license, I wanted to know:

1. Can I easily use an **Apache licensed library?
2. Do I have to do something special to be able to use it freely?
3. What are the differences between an Apache 2.0 library and a MIT?

Sorry for these questions but I would like to feel comfortable and have no future problems ..

I still do not know if my app can be downloaded for free or by payment .. this is a problem for the Apache license?

This is the Library https://github.com/google/tink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apache License 2.0 is a permissive open source license and can be used in any kind of software, including paid applications. This is very similar to the MIT license. However, the Apache license is much more detailed and legally precise.

- Like the MIT license, you must give any recipients of the software a copy of the license and copyright notices. The Tink project does not contain any very visible copyright notices, but some files contain a “Copyright 2017 Google” statement.
- If the project contains a NOTICE file, you must include a copy of that file as well. Tink does not contain a NOTICE file.
- If you modify Tink, you must add a “prominent notice” to modified files. You can however license your modifications under whatever terms you wish, as long as you otherwise comply with the license.

The Apache license has one big advantage over the MIT license: it includes an explicit patent grant, at no cost! Google cannot sue your for patent infringement for your use of Tink. This patent license terminates if you claim in a lawsuit that some part of Tink is patent infringement, but that doesn't matter if you don't hold any patents. The MIT license does not provide similar legal certainty with regard to patents.

As to how you should display the Apache license and the copyright notices in your application, you would usually show an “Open Source” menu item in your app's settings screen. See also my answer [What to keep in mind when releasing an app which uses libraries licensed under the Apache 2.0 License?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/284860/60357) on Software Engineering.